# Crystal Report Split(): Splitting Names

Tags: crystal-reports

I have tried Split() function in crystal report. But got an error like this when using preview. How to solve this.Please help.
[][2]

[Click here for my code and Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gh40m.png)

Comment: Could you provide more detail about Error and your code(`Split`) as well.

Comment: I have modified the question. Please take a look